# Подсчитать количество пользователей на канале Telegram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Проблема: после того, как пользователь вводит команду /MembersCount, в аргумент функции getChatMembersCount(channel) ничего не передается.

Как сделать так, чтобы после ввода команды /MembersCount пользователь мог ввести идентификатор канала?

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(msg):
    keyboard1 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
    keyboard1.row('/help', '/MembersCount')
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'Starting', reply_markup=keyboard1)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['MembersCount'])
def getChatMembersCount(channel):
    bot.get_chat_members_count(chat_id=channel)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ на ваш вопрос:

```
sw = {}

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(msg):
    keyboard1 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
    keyboard1.row('/help', '/MembersCount')
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'Starting', reply_markup=keyboard1)
    sw[msg.chat.id] = False

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handler(message):
    if message.chat.id in sw and sw[message.chat.id]:
        count = bot.get_chat_members_count(message.text)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, count) 
        sw[msg.chat.id] = False 

@bot.message_handler(commands=['MembersCount'])
def getChatMembersCount(channel):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Input chat_id:') 
    sw[msg.chat.id] = True
```

Но лучше, сделайте так, чтобы идентификатор канала передавался сразу внутри команды.

Like this:

> /MembersCount < chat_id >

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(msg):
    keyboard1 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
    keyboard1.row('/help', '/MembersCount')
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'Starting', reply_markup=keyboard1) 

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handler(message):
    if '/MembersCount' in message.text:
        cmnd = message.text.split() 
        count = bot.get_chat_members_count(cmnd[1])
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, count)
```